# Visual Studio doesn't recognize UnitTesting namespace

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, unit-testing

For some reason, the system doesn't recognize the namespace
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting". I am writing a code in VB.Net. How to fix it?

Thanks,
Yoav.

[image]

I have searched through Google, but didn't find a direct answer to my question. I am pretty sure it's about system definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add it as a reference to your project, hopefully using NuGet?

Solution Explorer > Right-click Project name > Manage NuGet Packages...